# How to numerically simulate a rolling object?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, computational-physics, simulations, rigid-body-dynamics

I am a maths person and definitely not a physics person, so maybe this is taught somewhere and I haven't learned it. I am trying to understand and figure out how to simulate rolling an object on a flat horizontal surface. In the case of rolling a circle, I understand that fine, it's essentially translating (moving) the circle horizontally while rotating the perimeter such that after one cycle of the parameter, the circle translates by the perimeter (length) of the circle. However, I am thinking about how this can be derived or generalised to e.g. ellipses and other stuff. I thought about another perspective which is a polygon, where you essentially rotate the entire shape around the rightmost contact point with the ground until there's a second contact point, then you repeat this process. However, it doesn't really work with round objects since there's only one contact point at a time. I suppose the derivation process for the circle equations would then be to imagine the circle having two infinitesimally closed contact points and do the rotating process, but if someone can explain it better it would be great. For example, what would the (differential?) equations be for the ellipse that starts at $(x_0, y_0) = (2\cos\theta, 1 + \sin\theta)$ where $\theta \in [0, 2\pi]$ and rolling the ellipse (to the right) on $y = 0$? Thanks!

(Also, the "speed" of the object doesn't really matter, I don't care about that part, just "where will the ellipse be if e.g. the center of the ellipse is at $x = 100$)

Comment: Why do you want to perform this simulation?  Also, do you know how to program a computer?  If so, what language?

Comment: @DavidWhite I wanted to look at the locus of the center of a rolling object, eg an ellipse or a rounded square. I am just curious hahaha. I do program in Python and C++ and few other languages (and a bit of Mathematica)

Comment: As long as there is no slip the total length of the curve that the contact point describes on both the surface and the shape of the rolling object is the same. This is not a physical situation, of course. In reality both surfaces will deform and there will be an actual area of contact. The deformation will not be energy conserving from a purely mechanical point of view (tires are being heated by rolling and there is roll resistance). Things get significantly more complicated with slip.

Comment: @GarethMa, you imply that you want an algorithm or pseudo-code that will allow you to find your answer for any given shape.  Is that correct?  And note: I don't see this as strictly being a physics problem, so this may not be the correct forum for your question.

Comment: @FlatterMann Sorry for not being clear, but yes I meant that there is no slip. So just a pure object rolling along a horizontal surface.

Comment: @DavidWhite If possible yes, both numerical methods or analytical (e.g. given an equation of the ellipse, how do i derive the differential equation for the equation for the ellipse at some time (with respect to some speed)). Sorry if this is not the correct forum, but this sounds like pure classical mechanics that I am supposed to know as a math student hahaha. Just a math solution (again, I am fine with equations) is fine too, it doesn't have to be any algorithm.

Comment: That's just the length of two curves being the same, then. It's two line integrals and a solver that makes both of them equal, isn't it?

Comment: @FlatterMann Wait, so I just setup a line integral that will go around the object parameter, then solve it to equal to my target distance travelled to find the new contact point, then "place" the object there (I guess rotate the object)? But that doesn't work for e.g. a square, or any non-convex shape

Comment: That will indeed only work for smooth convex shapes for which the curvature of the rolling body is smaller than the curvature of the ground, I suppose. For other shapes a pivoting algorithm that calculates the new contact point will be needed.

Comment: @FlatterMann I see, thanks a lot, maybe that's what I need. The idea seems so obvious now :)

Comment: Is this pure rolling, or you want to consider friction/slipping?

Comment: https://youtu.be/ZWWgGk9JU0E

Comment: @JohnAlexiou Thanks, that's a very nice video. I have answered already, but I want pure rolling, no friction no slipping, just rolling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

The equations of motion
\begin{align*}
&m\,\ddot{x}=-F_c\\
&I_E\,\ddot{\varphi}=\tau-F_c\,r_y(\varphi)-N\,r_x(\varphi)\quad,N=m\,g
\end{align*}
and the non holonomic constraint equation for the rolling condition.
\begin{align*}
  &\dot{x}-r_y(\varphi)\,\dot\varphi=0\quad\Rightarrow\\
  &\ddot{x}-r_y(\varphi)\,\ddot\varphi-\frac{d\,r_y}{d\varphi}\dot\varphi^2=0
\end{align*}

you obtain three equations for the unknowns $~\ddot{x}~~\ddot{\varphi}~,F_c~$

**Simulation**

first we have to create a lookup   table $~r_x=r_x(\varphi)~,r_y=r_y(\varphi),0\le\varphi\le 2\pi~$ from here we can obtain $~\frac{dr_y}{d\varphi}~$

now we can do the numerical simulation of the differential equations $~\ddot x~,\ddot\varphi~$

---

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will go through it first :)